# ElseIf condition issue. The code should set a status of an order based on the date and the values in 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
Hi all!

I have an issue with ElseIf statement. 
The code should set a status Overdue, Partial Overdue, Open etc. of an order based on the date (today) and the values in 2 columns: Open QTY (Z) and Confirmed quantity (W).

The problem is that the ElseIf goes from Canceleled to Partial overdue without any issues. However, it doesn't read the ElseIf for the Open status.

I have changed the code many times, but still cannot find where is the problem.

Here is my updated code:

Could you help?

Thank you in advance!

Cheers

I_K_M

```
Sub Status()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim x As Date

x = Date

m = Sheets("Input").Range("U:U").End(xlDown).Row

'Dim dateInMay As New System.DateTime(Today)

For i = 2 To m

 If Range("W" & i) = 0 Then
 Range("AC" & i) = "Cancelled"

ElseIf Range("Z" & i) = 0 Then
 Range("AC" & i) = "Delievered"

ElseIf Range("Z" & i) = Range("W" & i) And Range("AA2" & ii) < x Then
   Range("AC" & i) = "Overdue"

ElseIf Range("Z" & i) < Range("W" & i) And Range("AA2" & ii) < x Then
   Range("AC" & i) = "Partial Overdue"

ElseIf Range("AA2" & ii) > x + 1 Then
Range("AC" & i) = "Open"

Else
Range("AC" & i) = ""

ii = ii + 1

End If

Next

End Sub
```

So when the Range("AA2" & ii) = x aka the delivery date is today or tomorrow, is your code supposed to land in the final Else block?? For dates that equal (x) or (x + 1), you won't enter Overdue, Partial Overdue or Open. Is that what you want?

Yes, I would like to enter in "AC" the Status of the order: Overdue, Partial Overdue or Open. However, the code which I use: Open=Overdue. Which is wrong because the date is in the future x+1=> the orders are still open and NOT overdue.

I have problem that the code doesn't read the Open status the last ElseIf statement. Can I upload my sheet somewhere here?

Cheers ira

Comment: In your original question, please show the **results** of running your macro, and highlight the lines that are in error

Comment: So when the Range("AA2" & ii) = x aka the delivery date is today or tomorrow, is your code supposed to land in the final Else block??  For dates that equal (x) or (x + 1), you won't enter Overdue, Partial Overdue or Open. Is that what you want?

Comment: I'm really confused by what you're doing with Range("AA2" & ii). So, when you're looking at Row 2 for the other conditions, you're looking at row 20 for determining "Open" And ii only increments when none of the conditions is met? It would seem a lot more logical to get rid of ii and replace all references to Range("AA2" & ii) with Range("AA2" & i) if all you want to do is make determinations based on the columns within a single row.

Comment: Also, when the value of ii increases from 9 to 10, your reference is going to change from cell AA29 to cell AA210.

Comment: Yes Mark, I would like to enter in "AC" the Status of the order: Overdue, Partial Overdue or Open. However, the code which I use: Open=Overdue. Which is wrong because the date is in the future x+1=> the orders are still open and NOT overdue. 

I have problem that the code doesn't read the Open status the last ElseIf statement. Can I upload my sheet somewhere here?

Cheers ira

Answer (score 0):

I think the below should fix your issue. As described in the comments, I have eliminated the variable ii, changing all necessary references to i, and changed any references to "AA2" to "AA." This code will now make determinations based on the columns in a single row rather than sometimes examining a cell 20+ or 200+ rows down.

```
Sub Status()
Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim x As Date
x = Date
m = Sheets("Input").Range("U:U").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 2 To m
If Range("W" & i) = 0 Then
Range("AC" & i) = "Cancelled"
ElseIf Range("Z" & i) = 0 Then
Range("AC" & i) = "Delivered"
ElseIf Range("Z" & i) = Range("W" & i) And Range("AA" & i) < x Then
Range("AC" & i) = "Overdue"
ElseIf Range("Z" & i) < Range("W" & i) And Range("AA" & i) < x Then
Range("AC" & i) = "Partial Overdue"
ElseIf Range("AA" & i) > x + 1 Then
Range("AC" & i) = "Open"
Else
Range("AC" & i) = ""
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: if "ii" was 0 when "i" was 2, why not write "(i-2)"?

Comment: Hi Noldor130884, my assumption is that ii was just left over from a previous version of the code where OP was using a Do Until or a While loop instead of the For loop. He says "The code should set a status Overdue, Partial Overdue, Open etc. of an order based on the date (today) and the values in 2 columns: Open QTY (Z) and Confirmed quantity (W)." Based on that, I think he wants to just look at the values of the different columns all within the same row and not look at the value two rows up.